# Specification of Includes and Excludes for Gradle Copy Tasks

Tags: java, gradle, copy

I have a copy task with a set of inclusions

```
    task test_init(dependsOn: generate_scripts){

    doFirst{
        mkdir (project.test_dir)
        mkdir (project.test_data_dir)
        mkdir (project.test_reports_dir)
        mkdir (project.test_logs_dir)
        mkdir (project.test_jasper_dir)
        mkdir (project.test_chart_dir)
    }

    doLast{
        copy
        {
            from"${test_script_hsqldb_nd}"
            into"${test_dir}"
        }
        copy
        {
            from"${test_script_create_constraints}"
            into"${test_dir}"
        }
        copy
        {
            from"${test_script_drop_constraints}"
            into"${test_dir}"
        }

        copy
        {
            from fileTree(dir: "${test_src_dir}",
            include:
            [
                '**/*.xml',
                '**/*.dtd',
                '**/*.csv',
                '**/*.mpp',
                '**/*.dic',
                '**/*.png',
                '**/*.properties'
            ])
            into"${build_classes_dir}"


        }
    }

//////THIS IS MY UGLY WORKAROUND////////////////////
    doLast{
        delete "${build_classes_dir}/com/XXXX/ppm/gantt"
        delete "${build_classes_dir}/com/XXXX/ppm/util"
        delete "${build_classes_dir}/com/XXXX/ppm/action/pageinformation"
    }
}
```

It works fine and dandy however there are 3 folders that are included in the 'from' tree of the last copy task that don't contain any files pertinent to the inclusions, as such following the task they are empty. 
I would like to have them excluded from the task altogether but I'm having troubles achieving that. Currently I am simply deleting them in the final final 'doLast' block and that seems a little stupid.
I have tried

```
exclude: "${test_src_dir}/com/XXXX/ppm/gantt",..**similar statements for other files**
```

and

```
exclude: "${test_src_dir}/**/gantt"
```

Though I have a feeling the '**' usage isn't right in this context.
I would appreciate any input people may have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try `includeEmptyDirs = false`, although I'm not completely sure if it will work for non-empty directories that only become empty after honoring includes/excludes.

PS: It's usually better to use a `Copy` task (also shows how your syntax can be simplified a lot):

```
task test_init(type: Copy, dependsOn: generate_scripts) { 
    from test_script_hsqldb_nd
    from test_script_create_constraints
    from test_script_drop_constraints
    into test_dir
}

// assuming build_classes_dir is not a subdirectory of test_dir, we need a
// second Copy task (every Copy task has a single top-level destination dir)
task test_init_2(type: Copy, dependsOn: generate_scripts) {  
    from test_src_dir
    into build_classes_dir
    include '**/*.xml'
    include '**/*.dtd'
    include '**/*.csv'
    include '**/*.mpp'
    include '**/*.dic'
    include '**/*.png'
    include '**/*.properties'
    includeEmptyDirs = false
}
```

Both the `Copy` task and the `copy` method will create target directories automatically.

Comment: Thank you @PeterNiederwieser I had tried the 'includeEmptyDirs' property before but I had it in the wrong part of the method.
I have cleaned up the syntax too, thanks for that little tip.

Comment: I have the same situation. I have valid files under folder/subfolder during Copy task. Later during .jar operation, I delete few *pattern*.x files which leaves some of the sub/folders empty using "delete filetree(dir: "xxxxx", include: "somepattern") way.... during this time these folders gets empty. Is there any way I can also delete those folders/subfolders which become empty. ...How can I acheive that. Thanks. I agree includeEmptyDirs = false during copy, works during initial copy not when copy is already done. I also tried tasks.withType(Delete) { includeEmptyDirs = true }, didn't work.